# Why does Python welch give me a different answer from MATLAB's pwelch?

Tags: matlab, python, sampling, power-spectral-density, scipy

I am trying to implement the following line of MATLAB code:

`[pxx, f] = pwelch(data,[],[],4096,F_S)`

in Python. Knowing that MATLAB using a Hamming window type that uses 8 segment with 50% overlap, my attempt was

`freq, PSD =` 
 `signal.welch(data, F_S, window='hamming', nperseg=None, noverlap=None, nfft=4096)`

However, I receive different results that on the eye look similar but aren't. MATLAB predicts a power peak of 0.13 at the 2nd entry of the `pxx` vector, while Python predicts a power peak of 0.33 at the 32nd entry of the `PSD` vector. Did I do something wrong?

[image: The image comparison]

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46775223) be the answer?

Comment: I have added the detrend = False tag, and I used Jdip's suggestion of defining the window length manually, and now it works fine! TY!

Comment: @JoJo, please mark the answer as "accepted" so that it doesn't stay in the "unanswered" category :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters for the sciPy implementation look wrong. Matlab does divide the input data into 8 segments so you need to do the same with Python. SciPy by default sets each segment to 256 samples (see [sciPy.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html?highlight=welch))

You need something like:

```
N = np.floor(len(data)/8) #sets the frame length the same as Matlab's default
freq, PSD = 
   signal.welch(data, F_S, window='hamming', nperseg=N, noverlap=None, nfft=4096)
```

Better yet, define your own `window_length` (i.e `nperseg`) and `hop_length` (i.e `noverlap`), and re-do your comparison without relying on the default parameters of either functions.

I'd also suggest looking up the documentation for each, the scaling *might* be different depending on the implementation.

**EDIT**
Seems the default scaling is the same for both implementation ;)